# Serialize into an XML Fragment - not XML Document

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

How do I serialize an XML-serializable object to an XML fragment (no XML declaration nor namespace references in the root element)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a hack-ish way to do it without having to load the entire output string into an XmlDocument:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Example
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        Example example = new Example { Name = "Foo" };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));

        XmlSerializerNamespaces emptyNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        emptyNamespace.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output,
            new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
        serializer.Serialize(writer, example, emptyNamespace);

        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - I don't think it's really hackish at all. Maybe more set up work than I'd like to do. But, at the end, it's telling it what format the output should be before it does the work. That's not a hack. A hack would be to strip everything out after the fact etc.

Comment: I agree with Andrew that this is hackish. Unless I am doing something wrong, all my elements have the attribute 'xmlns=""'. Would have preferred that this not be present at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just serialize like you usually do, and then use the `Root` property from the resulting document.

You may need to clear the attributes of the element first.

Comment: +1 Sounds good to me but what I didn't explain in my question was that I'd prefer to produce a stream and not an XmlDocument.

Answer (score 0):

By the way this is awesome. 
I implemented this code to make it easy to work with xml fragments as classes quickly and then you can just replace the node when finished. This makes the transition between code and xml ultra-easy.

First create some extension methods.

```
public static class SerializableFragmentExtensions
{
    public static XElement ToElement(this ISerializableFragment iSerializableFragment)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(iSerializableFragment.GetType());
        var emptyNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        emptyNamespace.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

        var output = new StringBuilder();

        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output,
            new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });
        serializer.Serialize(writer, iSerializableFragment, emptyNamespace);
        return XElement.Parse(output.ToString(), LoadOptions.None);
    }
    public static T ToObject<T>(this XElement xElement)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        var reader = xElement.CreateReader();
        var obj = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Next Implement the required interface (marker interface--I know you are not supposed to but I think this is the perfect reason to it.)

```
public interface ISerializableFragment
{
}
```

Now all you have to do is decorate any Serializable class, you want to convert to an XElement Fragment, with the interface.

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeSerializableClass : ISerializableFragment
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Finally test the code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someSerializableClassObj = new SomeSerializableClass() {SomeData = "Testing"};
        var element = someSerializableClass.ToElement();
        var backToSomeSerializableClassObj = element.ToObject<SomeSerializableClass>();
    }
```

Thanks again for this amazingly useful code.

Comment: There was on problem I had immediately on trying this in my own project. With a text snippet that exactly followed the correct naming ,as in the example I provided, the code worked perfectly. I had a class name that didn't have the same name as the root element. The answer was simply adding the XmlRootAttribute on the class and naming it the same as the name of the root element in the xml. This worked without flaw. You can also be assured that any elements that are existent in the xmldocument that are not expressed in the class definition will not break the parsing.