# DataTable.WriteXML() without verbose Namespace and DataType declarations

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am serializing a simple DataTable to XML, and storing the result in a string. Using StringWriter and DataTable.WriteToXml, this has gone fine.

```
public class Parameters
{   private DataTable ParamList = new DataTable();

    public Parameters()
    {   //Default constructor, build datatable with two empty columns
        ParamList.TableName = "Parameter";
        ParamList.Columns.Add("Name",Type.GetType("System.String"));
        ParamList.Columns.Add("Value",Type.GetType("System.Object")); }
    ...
    public string ConvertToXML()
    {   string result;
        using(var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {   ParamList.WriteXml(sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works as advertised. HOWEVER, the XML is quite verbose when defining the  field:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ClientNumber</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00001</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>FirstName</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">John</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>LastName</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Smith</Value>
  </Parameter>
...
```

**I would like to eliminate all the namespace and datatype declarations** in the VALUE field, just like the NAME fields appear. I've toyed around with XmlWriterSettings(), but can't seem to find any settings to accomplish this. Any thoughts? Is what I propose possible?

(Note 1: My intent is simply to document the fields and values in the datatable to a SQL table, and since the number of fields and values may vary, this seemed like the simplest approach. The XML won't be read back in, so strongly-typed data elements are not of great importance to my goal.)

(Note 2: I'd like to achieve this without resorting to RegEx, but if that's my only option, that may be the direction I take.)

> Possible Duplicate? : [Serialize into an XML Fragment - not XML Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768432/serialize-into-an-xml-fragment-not-xml-document)

Looked into this, but couldn't adjust the syntax to work with a DataTable.

Comment: Why do you care how verbose it is?

Comment: The output is intended for human-consumption, and I'm just using the XML formatting as a convenient mode of keeping it organized.

Comment: DataTable gives you all the metadata you need to hand generate the simplest possible xml document. Just iterate across the rows & columns, outputing the results into a stringbuilder or use one of the xml apis.

Comment: Sounds manageable. I was just hoping for a built-in means of doing so, utilizing the WriteXML() function rather than programming a custom solution.

Comment: Just ran a test and confirmed the only reason the namespace declarations are being generated is because I defined the VALUE field of the datatable as Object so it could accept any datatype. If I change it to String, my problem is solved, but it doesn't benefit the rest of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution, but I await more experienced opinions before I declare this the Answer.

As I noted in my comments, the Namespace and Datatype declarations only appear on the Value field because it is cast as Object in the DataTable declaration. This has functional value, so I can't change it. But I CAN clone the table, change the datatype of the field while the cloned datatable is still empty, fill the table with data from the original datatable, then perform the same WriteXML() I had originally.

```
Public class Parameters
{   private DataTable ParamList = new DataTable();

    public Parameters()
    {   //Default constructor, build datatable with two empty columns
        ParamList.TableName = "Parameter";
        ParamList.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
        ParamList.Columns.Add("Value",typeof(object)); }
    ...
    public string ConvertToXML()
    {   string result;

        //Clone Datatable, change Object field to datatype String
        var dtClone = ParamList.Clone();
        dtClone.Columns["Value"].DataType = typeof(string);
        ParamList.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable(dtClone, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

        using(var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {   dtClone.WriteXml(sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ClientNumber</Name>
    <Value>00001</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>FirstName</Name>
    <Value>John</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>LastName</Name>
    <Value>Smith</Value>
  </Parameter>
...
```

Comment: Why didnt you do typeof string straight rather than changing again?ParamList.Columns.Add("Value",Type.GetType("System.Object"));

Comment: Didn't even know that syntax existed until today! Made the change, thanks~

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete program that I have tried- So Holder for holding anything and serializing the value:

```
 public class Holder:IXmlSerializable
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
       writer.WriteString(Data.ToString());
    }
}
public class DataTableManager
{
    public static void Save()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("table1");
        DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn("Column1",typeof(string));
        DataColumn dataColumn2 = new DataColumn("Column2",typeof(Holder));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn2);
        dataTable.Rows.Add("ro2", new Holder(){Data = 1});
        dataTable.Rows.Add("ro3", new Holder() { Data = "Test" });
        dataTable.Rows.Add("ro4", new Holder() { Data = new decimal(10) });

        Debug.WriteLine(dataTable.Namespace);
        //To file:
        dataTable.WriteXml(@"c:\development\datatable.xml",XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
        //To string
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        dataTable.WriteXml(new StringWriter(stringBuilder));
        Debug.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

This produces the xml without any namespaces and will create three rows as above.
[image]

Comment: Just tried your recommendation, no change. If you change typeof(long) to typeof(object), that should mirror my setup.

Comment: Tested your StringBuilder addendum, still no change.

Comment: @Avneesh - can you please create a small sample and show the output please? Sometimes people have a good answer that may not work for the OP but will work in the general case.

Comment: I have pasted the whole program above and it is much cleaner than using clone I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you did above is actually what Avneesh suggested (before editing).

If you really want to suffer then inherit XmlWriter. It is abstract class. To use it in your serialization do this:

```
DataTable dt;

var myXmlSerialization = new MyXmlWriter();

dt.WriteXml(myXmlSerialization);
```

Sample of XmlWriter implementation can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWellFormedWriter.cs)

**I advise you not to.**

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. If you have SomeDataSet, just set it's prefix and namespace to null:

```
SomeDataSet.Prefix = null;
SomeDataSet.Namespace = null;
SomeDataSet.Table.WriteXml(filename);
```

Comment: Tried this suggestion in my sample code: added Prefix = null and Namespace = null to DataTable declaration. But output was unchanged.

Comment: Try to do this on DataSet that contains your table. I also failed width DataTable, but succeed with DataSet that contains that DataTable